# Same URL fails for Illegal character in query

Tags: java, android, url, uri

I'm stumped on how this fails. I've done a bit of reading on URL encoding and am confused why passing the same string however one constructed through httpurirequest fails.

```
list = 1336463

String listing2 = new String("https://api.prosper.com/api/Listings$filter=ListingNumber%20eq%20" + list);
```

While this works

```
    String listing2 = new String("https://api.prosper.com/api/Listings?$filter=ListingNumber%20eq%201336463");
```

Both of these produce the same string.

Here's my stacktrace

```
     04-22 17:14:43.196: D/Plog(28329): https://api.prosper.com/api/Listings?$filter=ListingNumber%20eq%201336463 
04-22 17:14:43.196: D/AbsListView(28329): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-22 17:14:43.196: D/AbsListView(28329): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-22 17:14:43.196: W/dalvikvm(28329): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41848898)
04-22 17:14:43.206: D/AbsListView(28329): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-22 17:14:43.246: D/AbsListView(28329): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-22 17:14:43.276: D/AbsListView(28329): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-22 17:14:43.286: D/AbsListView(28329): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 73: https://api.prosper.com/api/Listings?$filter=ListingNumber%20eq%201336463 
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at com.example.prosperapp.ListingDetail.listingscall(ListingDetail.java:323)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at com.example.prosperapp.ListingDetail$CallAPI.doInBackground(ListingDetail.java:136)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at com.example.prosperapp.ListingDetail$CallAPI.doInBackground(ListingDetail.java:1)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-22 17:14:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(28329):    ... 4 more
```

After trimming the string I now see.

```
04-22 18:49:18.202: I/System.out(3829): 54
04-22 18:49:18.202: I/System.out(3829): 51
04-22 18:49:18.202: D/AbsListView(3829): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-22 18:49:18.202: D/AbsListView(3829): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-22 18:49:18.202: W/dalvikvm(3829): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41848898)
04-22 18:49:18.222: D/AbsListView(3829): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-22 18:49:18.222: D/AbsListView(3829): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-22 18:49:18.222: D/AbsListView(3829): unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=73; index=73
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at com.example.prosperapp.ListingDetail.listingscall(ListingDetail.java:323)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at com.example.prosperapp.ListingDetail$CallAPI.doInBackground(ListingDetail.java:137)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at com.example.prosperapp.ListingDetail$CallAPI.doInBackground(ListingDetail.java:1)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-22 18:49:18.222: E/AndroidRuntime(3829):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: I suspect listing contains some space at the beginning or end. Try `listing.trim()` when constructing `listing2`

Comment: This wasn't it but not a bad idea to keep things clean. Thanks

Comment: Index 73 is at the very end of your string. I can create a URI with the exact text you're showing here. There must be some invisible control character at the end of your string.

Comment: By the way, why are you writing `new String(string expression)`? There's no reason to be wrapping it in a call to the String ctor.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    Illegal character in query at index 73:
      https://api.prosper.com/api/Listings?$filter=ListingNumber%20eq%201336463 
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
```

The URI as displayed in the stack trace only appears to be 73 characters long (thus, with indices from 0 to 72). There must be some control character at the end of it which is causing it to fail.

Try this:

```
System.out.println((int) listing2.charAt(73));
```

I think you'll find that there is either a carriage return, line feed, or CRLF sequence at the end of your string. Any newline sequence would cause the exception you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks that returned 32 so it looks like there was an extra space, strange since I trimmed it above.  I just added .trim() and I'm now finding a new issue. This again is appearing if I use the string that I'm creating using list.